# Select non-task workorders, but include the costs of the tasks

Tags: sql, oracle

IBM's Maximo Asset Management platform has a WORKORDER table (265 columns).

**Details:**

The WORKORDER table contains two different kinds of rows:

- WO records (istask = 0)
- Task records (istask = 1).

The table has columns that store the *actual* costs (populated for both non-task WOs and for tasks):

- actlabcost (actual labor cost)
- actmatcost (actual material cost)
- actservcost (actual services cost)
- acttoolcost (actual tool costs)

---

**View:**

I've written a query/view that selects **non-task** WOs.

For those non-task workorders, the view rolls up the costs from the related tasks and summarizes them in these columns:

- actlabcost_incltask
- actmatcost_incltask
- actservcost_incltask
- acttoolcost_incltask
- acttotalcost_incltask

I plan to use the view for multiple reports. So I've included all 265 columns in the view via `select *` (although, Oracle will convert the `select *` to actual column names when the view is created).

```
--WO_INCL_TASK_ACT_VW (non-task WOs, includes task actuals)
select 
    t.task_actlabcost, 
    t.task_actmatcost, 
    t.task_actservcost, 
    t.task_acttoolcost,
    t.task_acttotalcost,
    nt.actlabcost   + t.task_actlabcost     as actlabcost_incltask, 
    nt.actmatcost   + t.task_actmatcost     as actmatcost_incltask, 
    nt.actservcost  + t.task_actservcost    as actservcost_incltask, 
    nt.acttoolcost  + t.task_acttoolcost    as acttoolcost_incltask,
    t.task_acttotalcost + nt.actlabcost + nt.actmatcost + nt.actservcost + nt.acttoolcost as acttotalcost_incltask, 
    nt.*
from 
    workorder nt --non-task WOs
left join
    (
    select 
        parent,  
        sum(actlabcost)  as task_actlabcost, 
        sum(actmatcost)  as task_actmatcost, 
        sum(actservcost) as task_actservcost, 
        sum(acttoolcost) as task_acttoolcost,
        sum(actlabcost) + sum(actmatcost) + sum(actservcost) + sum(acttoolcost) as task_acttotalcost 
    from 
        workorder 
    group by
        parent,
        istask
    having
        istask = 1
    ) t                --tasks
    on nt.wonum = t.parent
where
    nt.istask = 0
```

**Question:**

The view works just fine. However, it's fairly lengthy for what it does.

Can it be improved?

Comment: Are these columns - `sum(actlabcost) + sum(actmatcost) + sum(actservcost) + sum(acttoolcost) as task_acttotalcost ` - nullable?

Comment: @Reinderien I did a search on the table for null values. I couldn't find any. So I think the application must be preventing nulls and storing zeros instead. https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9As1.png. If those columns were nullable, would it compromise my query?

Comment: @Reinderien I looked at the application too. It seems to default to zero, not null. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPiwW.png

Comment: _would it compromise my query?_ No, but it would affect my suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you say that

> I plan to use the view for multiple reports. So I've included all 265 columns in the view via select *

but given the truly absurd column count in that table, I would consider a select-splat to be a very last resort. Are you able to narrow this at all?

Generally your query seems sane. Since you say that the following columns are non-nullable,

```
sum(actlabcost) + sum(actmatcost) + sum(actservcost) + sum(acttoolcost)
```

should be equivalent to

```
sum(actlabcost + actmatcost + actservcost + acttoolcost)
```

Comment: Right. Regarding the second option: summing a null instead of a zero would result in a null, which is not what I want.

Comment: Right; but you told me that there aren't any so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: If a workorder doesn't have any tasks that are joined to it, then I think `nt.actlabcost+t.task_actlabcost` would result in `null`, even if `nt.actlabcost` wasn't null. This would not be the desired result (`1 + null = null`).

Comment: `task_acttotalcost` is based on columns all from the same table, `workorder`, right? So they'll be all-null or all-non-null. No problem in using normal addition there. The trouble comes when you add `task_acttotalcost` to find `acttotalcost_incltask`, which has the null problem in your original post and needs a `coalesce` to zero.

Comment: I think I understand your point, but my concern is when there aren't any tasks associated with (aka joined to) the non-task workorders. So, `nt.actlabcost+t.task_actlabcost` could end up being `1243.00 + null = null`.

Comment: Let's continue this chat in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116444/nullables-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to get the cost of a work order including its children, if it has any, by joining from workorder `nt` to your in-line view `t` where `nt.wonum = t.parent`.

Are you aware that there is a `wogroup` column on `workorder` whose value is the same as `wonum` for non-task work orders and the same as `parent` on task work orders? So, you could remove the subquery from your query and just group your workorder records by `wogroup`.

For example, to get the actual labor cost for this work order and its children, instead of doing this:

```
select 
...
    nt.actlabcost   + t.task_actlabcost     as actlabcost_incltask, 
...
    nt.*
from 
    workorder nt --non-task WOs
left join
...
    ) t                --tasks
    on nt.wonum = t.parent
where
    nt.istask = 0
```

you could do this:

```
select 
    sum(actlabcost) as acttotalcost, 
    wogroup
from workorder
where woclass in ('WORKORDER', 'ACTIVITY')
    and siteid = 'SERVICES'
group by wogroup
```

On a separate point, in your in-line view, is there a good reason for `having istask = 1` instead of `where istask = 1`. In my experience, the `having` clause is used for conditions that use aggregate functions, and your "flat" `istask = 1` seems out of place there.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  This is an alternative code.  Please note that we emphasize the review portion of our name.  And this doesn't provide an explicit observation about the existing code.  Implicitly you seem to be suggesting that the existing code is more complicated than it needs to be.  Please say that explicitly and quote the code that you are simplifying.  As is, it's hard to see how this relates to the original code.

Comment: Good call. I should have used WOGROUP. Much simpler and faster.

Comment: Related post: [Group by x, get other fields too](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299932/group-by-x-get-other-fields-too-comparing-options-and-performance).

Answer (score 0):

This is the query I ended up going with. I believe it handles nulls correctly.

Note: The cost columns in the WORKORDER table are not nullable (`actlabcost`, `actmatcost`, `actservcost`, `acttoolcost`).

So that helps.

---

```
select 
    nt.wonum,
    nt.parent,
    nt.hierarchypath,
    nt.classstructureid,
    nt.division,
    nt.worktype,
    nt.status, 
    nt.glaccount, 
    nt.fircode, 
    actstart,
    actfinish,
    nt.siteid,
    nvl(nt.actlabcost,0) + nvl(t.t_actlabcost,0) as actlabcost,
    nvl(nt.actmatcost,0) + nvl(t.t_actmatcost,0) as actmatcost,
    nvl(nt.actservcost,0) + nvl(t.t_actservcost,0) as actservcost,
    nvl(nt.acttoolcost,0) + nvl(t.t_acttoolcost,0) as acttoolcost,
    nvl(t.t_acttotalcost,0) + nvl(nt.actlabcost,0) + nvl(nt.actmatcost,0) + nvl(nt.actservcost,0) + nvl(nt.acttoolcost,0) as acttotalcost,
    coalesce(nt.parent, nt.wonum) as parent_group --only works when WO hierarchy is 1 or 2 levels (not more)
from 
    workorder nt --non-task WOs
left join
    (
    select 
        parent, 
        sum(actlabcost) as t_actlabcost,
        sum(actmatcost) as t_actmatcost,
        sum(actservcost) as t_actservcost,
        sum(acttoolcost) as t_acttoolcost,
        sum(actlabcost + actmatcost + actservcost + acttoolcost) as t_acttotalcost
    from 
        workorder 
    where
        istask = 1
        and woclass in ('WORKORDER', 'ACTIVITY')
        and siteid = 'SERVICES'
    group by
        parent
    ) t --tasks
    on nt.wonum = t.parent
where
    nt.istask = 0
    and woclass in ('WORKORDER', 'ACTIVITY')
    and siteid = 'SERVICES'
```

Comment: It's time to get out of the habit of using `NVL()` and use `COALESCE()` instead. `NVL()` can implicitly convert to a character, isn't in the SQL standard, and doesn't perform short-circuiting. `COALESCE()` fixes all these problems.